# jQuery event on element when mouseover on other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically, I got a bunch of pictures and a table with names. When someone hovers the mouse over a picture, I want the name of that picture (name in the table) to light up, glow, whatever. My problem is I don't know how to trigger an event for an element when a different event is focused/'mouseovered'.

Please do help? (JS or jquery, either works)

Comment: you can simply trigger an event on the table element inside the function handling mouseover event for image. To get a solution in code, try sharing your existing code using jsfiddle

Comment: I'm quite confident than GOOGLE could help you on this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exectly what you asked, it does not triggers events. However this is possible solution if you need to highlight some corresponding title for the image. Whatever, see this example http://jsfiddle.net/qYsu9/

```
$('ul img').hover(function() {
  var index = $(this).data('title');
  $('table .title').removeClass('active').filter('.title-' + index).addClass('active');
});
```

So you just add an active class to a corresponding title.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question but thank you, you nailed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `$('#caption').trigger('mouseovere');` is what you need.

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/